# Expandable RecyclerView items, not working with data update

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have created a recyclerview with expandable items to display an `EventDisplay` list. In my ViewHolder class I have

```
public void onBind(EventDisplay eventDisplay, ClickListener clickListener, ListAdapter adapter) {
            // ...
            expandingView.setVisibility(eventDisplay.isExpanded ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            
            itemView.setOnClickListener((view) -> {
                // ...
                eventDisplay.isExpanded = !eventDisplay.isExpanded;
                adapter.notifyItemChanged(getAdapterPosition());

            });
            
}
```

which works as intended. However, the problem arises when the data is updated. Some items need an extra click in order to expand and un-expand properly again. It appears the problem is only for the view holders that are visible or are loaded when `updateItems` is called. Why is it as if the view holders suddenly lag one step behind when the data is changed, and how do I fix this?
Relevant code:

```
private ClickListener clickListener;
    private SortedList<EventDisplay> sortedList;
    private List<EventDisplay> allEventDisplays = new ArrayList<>(); // copy of data in sortedList
    protected MainListAdapter(ClickListener clickListener) {
        sortedList = new SortedList<>(EventDisplay.class, new SortedListAdapterCallback<EventDisplay>(this) {
            @Override
            public int compare(EventDisplay o1, EventDisplay o2) {
                //...
            }

            @Override
            public boolean areContentsTheSame(EventDisplay oldItem, EventDisplay newItem) {
                return oldItem.event.getTitle().equals(newItem.event.getTitle()) && oldItem.isExpanded == newItem.isExpanded;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean areItemsTheSame(EventDisplay item1, EventDisplay item2) {
                return item1.event.getId() == item2.event.getId();
            }
        });
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
    }

    public void updateItems(List<Event> events) {
        // preserves isExpanded on all old items while updating to the new list
        ArrayList<EventDisplay> new_eventDisplays = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Event new_event: events) {
            boolean isExpanded = false; // false is default
            for(EventDisplay old_eventDisplay: allEventDisplays) {
                int ID = old_eventDisplay.event.getId();
                if(new_event.getId() == ID)
                    isExpanded = old_eventDisplay.isExpanded;
            }
            new_eventDisplays.add(new EventDisplay(new_event, isExpanded));
        }
        allEventDisplays.clear();
        allEventDisplays.addAll(new_eventDisplays);
        sortedList.replaceAll(new_eventDisplays.toArray(new EventDisplay[0]));
    }
```

Comment: How do you handle when new date arrive?

Comment: @Ticherhaz FreePalestine Can you clarify? When there is new data, `updateItems` is called.

Comment: I have suggestion like make a `swipeRefreshLayout`, you need to swipe to get new data or you can use while loop every 5 seconds will get new data.

Comment: I hope this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/51290815/9346054